# Alternate Row Colors in Range

Tags: excel, vba

I've come up with the following to alternate row colors within a specified range:

```
Sub AlternateRowColors()
Dim lastRow as Long

lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For Each Cell In Range("A1:A" & lastRow) ''change range accordingly
    If Cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then ''highlights row 2,4,6 etc|= 0 highlights 1,3,5
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 ''color to preference
    Else
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ''color to preference or remove
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

That works, but is there a simpler method?

The following lines of code may be removed if your data contains no pre-exisiting colors:

```
    Else
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternating row colors can be done using conditional formatting:

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Thnaks James. Could you show us an example of what that would look like please? Also, does CF work in v2003?

Comment: Does the attached image not show up for you? I took a screen shot of the whole thing. It works in Excel 2000, so I assume that it will also work in Excel 2003

Comment: Ah that explains it. I'm at work and our IT team seem to have an internet policy similar to that of North Korea: heavily censored. I'll have a look when I get home.

Comment: If I try this in Excel for Mac 2011 it returns an error telling my that my formula contains an error.

Comment: The problem with Conditional Formatting is that it's "super-volatile". Ever time you make a change on the sheet, it recalculates all the conditional cells even if they're not part of what was changed. Setting Conditional on every row of a big spreadsheet will slow you down big time!

Answer (score 10):

I need to do this frequently and like to be able to easily modify the colors I'm using for the banding. The following sub makes it very easy:

```
Sub GreenBarMe(rng As Range, firstColor As Long, secondColor As Long)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(ROW(),2)=0"
    rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = firstColor
    rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(ROW(),2)<>0"
    rng.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = secondColor
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Sub TestGreenBarFormatting()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim firstColor As Long
    Dim secondColor As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1:D12")
    firstColor = vbGreen
    secondColor = vbYellow

    Call GreenBarMe(rng, firstColor, secondColor)
End Sub
```

Comment: I get 'invalid procedure' error at line: 

rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(ROW(),2)=0"

Comment: I solved it. My problem was that my Excel is in portuguese language, then I needed to translate the formula to portuguese equivalent. e.i "=MOD(ROW(),2)<>0" to ""=MOD(LIN();2)<>0""  ;)

Comment: Linha em vez de Row? Valeu!

Answer (score 4):

I needed a macro that would color every second row in a range, using only those rows that were visible.  This is what I came up with.  You don't have to loop through the rows.

```
Sub Color_Alt_Rows(Rng As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Rng = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=mod(row()+1,2)"
    Rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 34
End Sub
```

Try it out with `Color_Alt_Rows Range("a2:d5")`

Answer (score 2):

## My Solution

> A subroutine to assign to a button or some code

```
Public Sub Band_Goals()
    'Just pass the start and end rows
    'You will have to update the function to select the
    'the correct columns

    BandRows_Invisble 12, 144

End Sub
```

### The Function

```
Private Sub BandRows_Invisble(StartRow As Integer, EndRow As Integer)

    Dim i As Long, nothidden As Boolean


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Range("A" & StartRow & ":K" & EndRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    For i = StartRow To EndRow
        If Not Rows(i).Hidden Then
            nothidden = nothidden + 1
            If Not nothidden Then
                    'Download this app to help with color picking
                    'http://www.iconico.com/download.aspx?app=ColorPic
                    Range("A" & i & ":K" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(196, 189, 151)

            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'--- Alternate Row color, only non-hidden rows count

Sub Test()

Dim iNumOfRows As Integer, iStartFromRow As Integer, iCount As Integer
iNumOfRows = Range("D61").End(xlDown).Row '--- counts Rows down starting from D61

For iStartFromRow = 61 To iNumOfRows

    If Rows(iStartFromRow).Hidden = False Then '--- only non-hidden rows matter

        iCount = iCount + 1

        If iCount - 2 * Int(iCount / 2) = 0 Then
            Rows(iStartFromRow).Interior.Color = RGB(220, 230, 241)
        Else
            Rows(iStartFromRow).Interior.Color = RGB(184, 204, 228)
        End If

    End If
Next iStartFromRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can delete the `else` part, since you will leave it in the default color

Comment: Well pointed out. I needed that for my own project as the data arrives with alternate row colors and I have to resort it based on values. The else cleans everything up for me, but totally appropriate to remove it otherwise. Thanks Chuck.

Answer (score 0):

In my Excel 2010, there is an option to format as table, where you can also select a range and headers. No need for scripting.
[image: Excel Table]

Comment: i think you missed the point of the question

Comment: @lalachka I think you missed the point of the answer. It offers tables with alternating row colors. How does that not answer the question?

Comment: The range changes, thus the need for automation.

Answer (score 0):

set these up initialized somewhere:

```
Dim arr_Lng_Row_Color(1) As Long
arr_Lng_Row_Color(0) = RGB(int_Color_1_R, int_Color_1_G, int_Color_1_B)
arr_Lng_Row_Color(1) = RGB(int_Color_2_R, int_Color_2_G, int_Color_2_B)
```

On any row you wish this will set the color

```
ws_SomeSheet.Rows(int_Target_Row).EntireRow.Interior.Color = arr_Lng_Row_Color(int_Target_Row Mod 2)
```

Comment: Not much different from what he already did