# Different background colors for even and odd rows

Tags: excel

How can I set up a column in Excel so that every other line has a different background color, even when I insert a new row?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629100/excel-vba-alternate-row-colors-in-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a table is one way to do that.

Select the cells that should have the alternating color formatting, click "Insert" and "Table" on the ribbon. Tell Excel whether your data has a header row, and click ok.

If you would prefer to clear the arrow that appears on the first row (for setting filter options), click anywhere in the table, then click "Data" and deselect "Filter" on the ribbon.

If you add a value in the row just beneath the table, the table and background color formatting will expand to include the additional row.

Answer (score 3):

Apply Conditional Formatting, with two rules, each with a different background colour

```
=ISEVEN(ROW())
```

and

```
=ISODD(ROW())
```

Comment: First result using Google with query `excel conditional formatting alternate row` returns [this](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/alternate_row_shading_using_conditional_formatting/)

Comment: @what - The link I suggested works fine for me. Highlight the range you want to format (e.g. click top left hand box for entire sheet), go to conditional formatting, add the formula in the `formula is` section, and pick a format for the row.

Comment: @what if you are using a non-English version, you need to [translate function names](http://dolf.trieschnigg.nl/excel/index.php#).