# Too many different cell formats. Loop always stops at same index. VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I know this question came up several times already, but I believe that my problem is slightly different.

My goal is to color format every second line one an excel sheet for visual reasons. The code for that looks like this:

```
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lC = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 2 To lastRow
        On Error GoTo skipColor
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1).Address, ws.Cells(i, lC).Address)
        rng.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            rng.Interior.TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
        Else
            rng.Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        End If
skipColor:
        Debug.Print Err.Description
Next i
```

The iteration of the loop always stops at exact the same line. It seems as if Excel cache is full and no more cell formats can be saved. I tried the solution (second answer) from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449755/too-many-different-cell-formats) and used it for every iteration of the loop. No success.

One more thing: even though I added the `On Error Goto skipColor` line, it still shows me the error message.

EDIT: The line that is highlighted when I hit debug on the error message is: `rng.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1`.

Comment: How about using conditional formatting as in the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629100/excel-vba-alternate-row-colors-in-range ?

Comment: What index does it stop at? The first? The second? Next to last? What is the error message?

Comment: @aphoria Index: 573 out of 742. Error message: "Run-time error '1004': Too many different cell formats.".

Comment: @LocEngineer, thanks but this produces a "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument." in the second line of the `GreenBarMe` sub. I deleted the first btw (that gave me the same error as in my question).

Comment: @moritz-schmitz-v-hülst No, not the VBA solution but the conditional formatting from the **accepted** answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not trapping the error correctly.  Because you have placed the label

```
skipColor:
```

inside the loop, you will hit the `Debug.Print` even though there is no error.

Comment: It shows me the error message as MsgBox not as Debug.Print.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft KB article [You receive a "Too many different cell formats" error message in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213904), it appears you have exceeded the allowed number of different cell formats.

From the article:

> **Cause**
>
> This problem occurs when the workbook contains more than
>   approximately 4,000 different combinations of cell formats in Excel
>   2003 or 64,000 in Excel 2007 and higher. A combination is defined as a
>   unique set of formatting elements that are applied to a cell. A
>   combination includes all font formatting (for example: typeface, font
>   size, italic, bold, and underline), borders (for example: location,
>   weight, and color), cell patterns, number formatting, alignment, and
>   cell protection.
>
> **NOTE**: If two or more cells share exactly the same formatting, they use
>   one formatting combination. However, if there are any differences in
>   formatting between the cells, each cell uses a different combination.
>
> In Excel style counts may increase when copying between workbooks
>   because custom styles are copied.
>
> A workbook that has more than 4,000 styles may open in Excel 2007 and
>   higher (because of the increased limitation for formatting) but result
>   in an error in Excel 2003.

The Resolution section provides a link to a tool called [XLStylesTool](https://sergeig888.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/net4-0-version-of-the-xlstylestool-is-now-available/) that may be able to help you cleanup you workbook.