# Range method not selecting right line in VBA - Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've been strugling to color alternate rows in a range in VBA. The problem is that the Range method seems not to select the proper range and I end up coloring adjacent cells. This is my desired output:

[image: desired output. Alternate rows colored by grey]

But, this is what I actually get:

[image]

This is the code I created:

```
Sub limpar_aniversariantes()
    Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("B4:D900").ClearContents
    'Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("B4:D900").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub


Sub gerar_lista_aniversariantes()
    limpar_aniversariantes
    Dim newrange As Range, rw As Range
    Sheets("Base de Alunos").Select
    Set newrange = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    CountInicioMes = 12
    CountInicio = 16
    Count = CountInicio
    count_first_line = 0
    For Each rw In newrange.Rows
        Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("B" & Count).Value = rw.Cells(2).Value
        Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("C" & Count).Value = Left(rw.Cells(5).Value, 2)
        Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("C" & Count).NumberFormat = "DD"
        Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("D" & Count).Value = UCase(rw.Cells(15).Value)
        'Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("A" & Count).Value = Count
        'pintar linhas alternadamente de cinza
        If Count Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("B" & Count & ":D" & Count).Interior.Color = RGB(211, 211, 211)
            Debug.Print ("B" & Count & ":D" & Count)
        End If
        'pegar mes dos aniversariantes, eh preciso pular header
        If count_first_line < 2 Then
            count_first_line = count_first_line + 1
            If count_first_line = 2 Then
               my_date = rw.Cells(5).Value
            End If
        End If
        'Debug.Print Left(rw.Cells(5).Value, 2)
        Count = Count + 1
        'Debug.Print rw.Cells(2).Value
    Next rw
    Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("B" & (CountInicio + 1) & ":D" & Count).Sort key1:=Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("C" & (CountInicio + 1) & ":C" & Count), _
    Header:=xlNo
    'limpar bordas anteriores
    Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Columns("B:D").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("B" & (CountInicio) & ":D" & (Count - 1)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    '.Weight = xlThin.ColorIndex = 3
    my_month = Mid(my_date, 4, 2)
    my_month_written = RetornarMes(CInt(my_month))
    Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("B" & CountInicioMes).Value = UCase(my_month_written)
    Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("B" & CountInicio).Value = "NOME"
    Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("C" & CountInicio).Value = "DIA"
    Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("D" & CountInicio).Value = "MODALIDADE"
    'mudar cor de fundo
    'Worksheets("Aniversariantes").Range("B" & CountInicio & ":D" & CountInicio).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    'Debug.Print my_month_written

End Sub
```

I am coping values from one worksheet to another and I am using MOD function to only color even lines. Everytime I copy these values the number of lines can change, that's why I need to do it by VBA. I am not mastered in VBA so any help is appreciated. I have struggled to do it the whole morning.

Edit: I notticed that choosing a row out of the PERSON's data table makes the Range().Interior.Color function works properly, the problem is inside the range.

Comment: Do you reset colors before running `gerar_lista_aniversariantes`? I see that second line that resets color in `limpar_aniversariantes` is commented.

Comment: You should use Conditional Formatting to create banded rows: [Creating Banded Rows in Excel](http://www.microknowledge.com/try-this-it-works/creating-banded-rows-in-excel/).  Alternatively, you could convert the list to a table.

Comment: You're right @JohnyL , I commented because this command is yielding me a problem because every line gets white. But I am reseting the colors manually for testing sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right,

Thanks to @Thomas Inzina comment, I realized that the formula "=MOD(ROW(),2)<>0" should be translated to my native excel language, e.i: Portuguese. Then the right translation is "=MOD(LIN();2)<>0". But, still I did not figure out why I was getting that weird behaviour that I showed in my question, instead I used this solution (with the proper formula) to solve my issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15957075/1171721

I am satisfied with that since I got what I wanted, but still if anyone discovers why I got this strange behaviour using the old approach, I will be happy to test the proposed solution for the sake of learning.